# Cold start splash screen with black bars on Android 7.1

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-7.1-nougat

I am implementing the "cold start" splash screen that Google is recommending

Source:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/  https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd
https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/launch-screens.html

However, on devices with *pure* Android 7.1 (Nexus 5X) the splash screen background is not resized correctly, creating black bars.

[image]

*The gray square is just to hide the logo since the app is not a published yet*

This is my background_splash.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_img"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_img"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is my theme:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: And this works correctly in other devices?

Comment: Yes, I tested on a OnePlus T3 with Android 7.1.1 and it works properly. Now I am running the apk on Firebase Test Lab to see if this happens on other devices as well.

Comment: Also, older Android versions work properly (on Nexus 5X and so on). Even on Android 7.0 works.

Comment: I have worked with the same style splash screen without any problem on Android 7.1, though am not sure about the "pure" android stock since I have used it on custom ROM.

Comment: @KaushikNP was your splash screen background a solid color or an image?

Comment: Sold color with image at the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the attribute *android:tileMode="clamp"* in the bitmap element I was able to fix the problem.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:tileMode="clamp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/hartwall_arena_bg"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/hartwall_arena_logo"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I do not have a good explanation for the "solution", so if someone explains it better I will mark it as the right response instead of mine : )

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the option `android:tileMode="clamp"` solve the problem with the black border, but the background image have distorted because according the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource

the `clamp` option `Replicates the edge color if the shader draws outside of its original bounds` so could look better with solid color backgrounds.

After 'solve' the black border issue using the clamp option but get the image distorted I know that the issue is on `bitmap` item in layer-list. So I add the bitmap as below and solve the issue :D

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>
</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_img"/>
    </item>
```

Assign scaleType in this code if possible.